# Error occured while calling the Jira API

Tags: python, rest, api, runtime-error, jira

I requested 500 issues at a time and per issues, there were around 4-6 comments in order to get the author's email of the comment I requested the Jira again for every comment. Basically, Number of requests I have made was nearer to the number of comments It could be around more than 20000. 
This is the code. There's no error in authentication. I use Jira library python.

```
count=0
comcount=0
k=0
while(comcount<=25000):
    print('Iterations {}'.format(k))
    for issue in jira.search_issues('updated >= 2016-08-09 AND updated <= 2018-08-10',startAt=k*500+1, maxResults=500):
        print('Project Count {}'.format(count))
        count += 1
        try:
            comments = jira.comments(issue)  # comments_b == comments_a
            for comment in comments:
                if getMailAddress(comment.author.name).split('@')[1].split('.')[0] != 'wso2':
                    comcount+=1
                    getreview(comment.body,comment.self,issue.self)
                    print('Comment Count {}'.format(comcount))
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error Occured',e)

    from time import sleep
    sleep(1)  # Time in seconds.
    k+=1
```

Here's the error html returned.

```
Technical details
Log's referral number: bced70c8-6e76-4553-8db9-ca3bb694f7e7

Cause
Referer URL: Unknown

com.atlassian.crowd.exception.runtime.UserNotFoundException: User <sathiyakugan@wso2.com> does not exist
com.atlassian.crowd.exception.runtime.UserNotFoundException: User <sathiyakugan@wso2.com> does not exist
    at com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.core.CrowdServiceImpl.setUserAttribute(CrowdServiceImpl.java:413) [embedded-crowd-core-2.8.8.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.core.CrowdServiceImpl.setUserAttribute(CrowdServiceImpl.java:392) [embedded-crowd-core-2.8.8.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.core.DelegatingCrowdService.setUserAttribute(DelegatingCrowdService.java:121) [embedded-crowd-core-2.8.8.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.crowd.embedded.core.FilteredCrowdServiceImpl.setUserAttribute(FilteredCrowdServiceImpl.java:51) [embedded-crowd-core-2.8.8.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.security.login.LoginStoreImpl.setLong(LoginStoreImpl.java:113) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.security.login.LoginStoreImpl.recordLoginAttempt(LoginStoreImpl.java:56) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.security.login.RecoveryLoginStore.recordLoginAttempt(RecoveryLoginStore.java:63) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.security.login.LoginManagerImpl.recordLoginAttempt(LoginManagerImpl.java:314) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.security.login.LoginManagerImpl.onLoginAttempt(LoginManagerImpl.java:215) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.security.login.JiraElevatedSecurityGuard.onSuccessfulLoginAttempt(JiraElevatedSecurityGuard.java:30) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.PasswordBasedLoginFilter.runAuthentication(PasswordBasedLoginFilter.java:142) [atlassian-seraph-3.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.PasswordBasedLoginFilter.login(PasswordBasedLoginFilter.java:78) [atlassian-seraph-3.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.BaseLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseLoginFilter.java:110) [atlassian-seraph-3.0.3.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraLoginFilter.doFilter(JiraLoginFilter.java:82) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32) [atlassian-core-5.0.6.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.internal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:79) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestSeraphFilter.doFilter(RestSeraphFilter.java:37) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:70) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:58) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.atlassian.johnson.filters.AbstractJohnsonFilter.doFilter(AbstractJohnsonFilter.java:59) [atlassian-johnson-core-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.johnson.JiraJohnson503Filter.doFilter(JiraJohnson503Filter.java:24) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394) [urlrewritefilter-4.0.3.jar:4.0.3]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.atlassian.jira.servermetrics.CorrelationIdPopulatorFilter.doFilter(CorrelationIdPopulatorFilter.java:30) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32) [atlassian-core-5.0.6.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:39) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.JiraAnalyticsFilter.doFilter(JiraAnalyticsFilter.java:42) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.analytics.client.filter.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:39) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.request.RedirectInterceptingFilter.doFilter(RedirectInterceptingFilter.java:21) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32) [atlassian-core-5.0.6.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.web.servlet.plugin.LocationCleanerFilter.doFilter(LocationCleanerFilter.java:36) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:58) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:56) [?:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:64) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:37) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:70) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:58) [atlassian-plugins-servlet-4.1.0.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:74) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.cache.AbstractCachingFilter.doFilter(AbstractCachingFilter.java:31) [atlassian-core-5.0.6.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32) [atlassian-core-5.0.6.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.encoding.AbstractEncodingFilter.doFilter(AbstractEncodingFilter.java:39) [atlassian-core-5.0.6.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32) [atlassian-core-5.0.6.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.PathMatchingEncodingFilter.doFilter(PathMatchingEncodingFilter.java:39) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32) [atlassian-core-5.0.6.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.atlassian.jira.startup.JiraStartupChecklistFilter.doFilter(JiraStartupChecklistFilter.java:62) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.MultipartBoundaryCheckFilter.doFilter(MultipartBoundaryCheckFilter.java:36) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.atlassian.jira.servermetrics.MetricsCollectorFilter.doFilter(MetricsCollectorFilter.java:25) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32) [atlassian-core-5.0.6.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:74) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraFirstFilter.doFilter(JiraFirstFilter.java:59) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilterInternal(GzipFilter.java:121) [atlassian-gzipfilter-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:92) [atlassian-gzipfilter-3.0.0.jar:?]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.gzip.JiraGzipFilter.doFilter(JiraGzipFilter.java:45) [classes/:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.InstantUpgradeHoldingFilter.doFilter(InstantUpgradeHoldingFilter.java:99) [classes/:?]
    at com.atlassian.core.filters.AbstractHttpFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpFilter.java:32) [atlassian-core-5.0.6.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1502) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1458) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_102]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_102]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.33]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_102]
```

Could I solve this problem?

Comment: By looking on the stacktrace, you tried to authenticate as a user "sathiyakugan@wso2.com" but such a user doesn't exist. You have to ensure your login credentials are correct. Can you login to the Jira instance with those credentials in the browser?

Comment: @enterbios  The above issue is an intermittent issue coming when sending requests to the JIRA API for some time with high throughput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this is an issue with the Jira API version

Multiple concurrent login attempts may throw a UserNotFoundException due to a race condition. A user will get 500 error as a response.
JIRA doesn't expect to have high concurrency for authentication requests. So initially problem is caused by very extensive authentications and better way to handle that is to reuse user session.

See docs: [jira-rest-api-example-cookie-based-authentication](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-apis/jira-rest-apis/jira-rest-api-tutorials/jira-rest-api-example-cookie-based-authentication)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like a known bug of JIRA which has been reported on [JRASERVER-62500](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRASERVER-62500) and I guess you are not using cookie based authentication as well.

I would recommend a cookie based authentication instead of the workaround of the bug. However, if you don't want this kind of authentication please move forward with the workaround.